# Setting variable name in async pipe

Tags: angular

I find myself in this situation quite often when I'd like to do the following:

```
<component-name 
  *ngIf="(referralsService.referrals$ | async; let referrals).length > 0
></component-name>
```

But this is not allowed.  Is there a better way to accomplish allowing me to name my variable so I can use it later while also calling `length` or something else on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in one `*ngIf` statement, but you can use the [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) wrapper:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="referralsService.referrals$ | async as referrals">
  <component-name *ngIf="referrals.length > 0"></component-name>
</ng-container>
```

> The Angular `<ng-container>` tag is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

For two observables you can use:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ 
  unused: (referralsService.unusedReferrals$ | async),
  used: ( referralsService.referrals$ | async) 
} as referrals">
  <component-name-1 *ngIf="referrals.used?.length > 0"></component-name-1>
  <component-name-2 *ngIf="referrals.unused?.length > 0"></component-name-2>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What if I had 2 async pipes? `<ng-container *ngIf="referralsService.referrals$ | async as referrals && referralsService.unusedReferrals$ | async as unusedReferrals">` doesn't seem to work

Comment: nope, you need to wrap that in another `<ng-container>` or use the object approach, but you'll lose some template code hinting

Comment: @JeremyThomas I've updated my answer if you need to use two observables. I personally am not a big fan of it